# Track driven distance of transporters in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent

I have modelled a fleet of AGVs as agents through `TransporterFleet` and `TransportControl` blocks.
The AGVs navigate in free space between different conveyors and their home locations.

Is it possible in Anylogic to track the driven distance for each AGV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transporter API includes a `getDistanceTravelled()` function since version 8.5.2

Answer (score -1):

Try using the "Logging" feature as that typically tracks the distance covered by agents in your model.

If it doesn't work for free-space AGVs, you have to record it manually (recurring event every x time-units)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I turend on the "Logging" feature but it does not log any distance covered, the log just stays empty. How could I record it manually? With which functions?

Comment: Create a cyclic event in your AGVs that check the current speed of them. Given the recurrence time, you can compute the distance travelled since the last event occurence and add that to a local variable "myDistance"